# Javascript - Alert users score and rank name

Tags: javascript, arrays, alert

I'm creating a javascript battleships game. The game works fine. I have created the game so that the user has a maximum of 25 misses - if they reach 25 then it's game over.

I now want to create a function that at the end of the game, the function checks the number of misses, and alerts the user their score and rank name.

I calculated the score by ((25/misses)*100).

So these are the possible scores with misses.

Misses | Score
(1      |2500)
(2      | 1250)
(3      | 833)
(4      | 625)
(5      | 500)
(6      | 417)
(7      | 357)
(8      | 313)
(9      | 278)
(10     | 250)
(11     | 227)
(12     | 208)
(13     | 192)
(14     | 179)
(15     | 167)
(16     | 156)
(17     | 147)
(18     | 139)
(19     | 132)
(20     | 125)
(21     | 119)
(22     | 114)
(23     | 109)
(24     | 104)
(25     | 0)

The rank names I have are 
1) Admiral of the Fleet
2) Admiral
3) Vice-Admiral
4) Rear-Admiral
5) Commodore
6) Killed In Action

These are how i've assigned the misses with the rank names.

Misses    | Rank Name
(0-12       | Admiral of the Fleet)
(13-15 | Admiral)
(16-19 | Vice-Admiral)
(20-24 |Commodore)
(25 | Kill In Action)

I have created a variable named 'misses'. Each time you miss, obviously the variable increments by one.

So let's say you just played and finished the game with 14 misses. I want the function to check the variable 'misses' and then assign it with the appropriate score and rank.

I reckon I could probably use an array for the misses with score. Any ideas what the exact code is? please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution:

```
function getRank(misses) {
    if (misses < 13)
        return 'Admiral of the Fleet';
    if (misses < 16)
        return 'Admiral';
    if (misses < 20)
        return 'Vice-Admiral';
    if (misses < 25)
        return 'Commodore';
    return 'Killed In Action';
}
```

You could also do something like this, which is more complicated and uses more memory, but would result in a faster `getRank()` - and if you won't have over 25 misses, the memory usage won't be a problem.

```
var getRank = (function () {
    var rank, i = 0, j,
        map = {},
        ranks = [
            [13, 'Admiral of the Fleet'],
            [16, 'Admiral'],
            [20, 'Vice-Admiral'],
            [25, 'Commodore'],
            [26, 'Killed In Action']
        ];
    for (j = 0; rank = ranks[j]; j++)
        for (; i < rank[0]; i++)
            map[i] = rank[1];
    return function (misses) {
        return map[misses];
    };
})();
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I alert the appropriate rank to the player though? For example, this is how I end my game.

    if(shipstate==17){
  alert("You win!");
  play=false;
 }

So that's where i'd want to alert them of their rank. How would I do this?

Comment: Using the above function, just `alert(getRank(misses));`, assuming that `misses` is assigned to the number of times the player missed.

Comment: Would I do a similar function for the score then? The getRank function works perfectly (thank you!).

Comment: Also is it meant to be like this? for (; i < rank[0]; i++)
or is there meant to be an i=0 at the beginning? :S

Comment: The initial `;` is intentional - `i` is being set to 0 at the top, and incremented forward a few steps in every iteration of its containing loop.

Comment: You can literally type `alert()` around the code in your question in order to alert the score ... or is that not what you're asking?

Comment: I might make an array with the scores, and then alert the array name [misses]. That way it will hopefully alert the score :) Though it would be userfriendly if it was alerted as just one box. Rather than do it seperately.